# Django: How to define __init__ function to django modelformset_factory?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a model formset and also for the field where users have to select a product, i don't want to show all the products in the database, i want to filter the products based on the logged in users.
by doing something like this on the ModelForm

```
class CartOrderItemsInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        ...
            
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CartOrderItemsInvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['product_obj'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

but is it possible to do this on a `modelformset_factory`

```
AuthorFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Author,
        fields=('name', 'age', 'gender', 'product'),
        extra=1,
        widgets={
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter Author Name here'
            }),
            'age': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter Author age'
            }),
            'gender': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter Author Gender'
            })
        }
        
        
)
```

How do i def the `__init__` on the `AuthorFormset = modelformset_factory()`

this is how my models looks

```
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    isbn_number = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='authors', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can override your AuthorFormset to filtered out what you want.
Such a thing like this :

```
class YourFilteredAuthorFormset(AuthorFormset):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        queryset = Products.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        self.form.base_fields['product'].queryset = queryset
```

Then use YourFilteredAuthorFormset instead of AuthorFormset ?